# Margins and vertical alignment of image inside div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div with content inside containing an image to the left and text to the right. I'm able to set the margins correctly and the left alignment correctly for the text, however, the image is not vertically aligned and the margins fall off on the right when viewed in the responsive stacked view.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6e6;
  color: #444;
  font: .9em Arial, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrapper div {
  min-height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#one {
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

#one img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 25px;
  max-width: 160px;
}

.helper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#two {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 910px) {
  #one {
    float: none;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: auto;
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one">
      <span class="helper"></span>
      <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="two">
      <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
      <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere
        ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
      <br>
      <p>
        <p>
          https://google.com/
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one">
      <span class="helper"></span>
      <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="two">
      <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
      <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere
        ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
      <br>
      <p>
        <p>
          https://google.com/
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added

```
height:100%;
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
```

to `#one`

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 40px;
  background-color: #e6e6e6e6;
  color: #444;
  font: .9em Arial, sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrapper div {
  min-height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#one {
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

#one img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-height: 25px;
  max-width: 160px;
}

.helper {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#two {
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 910px) {
  #one {
    float: none;
    margin-right: 0;
    width: auto;
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one">
      <span class="helper"></span>
      <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="two">
      <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
      <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere
        ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
      <br>
      <p>
        <p>
          https://google.com/
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="one">
      <span class="helper"></span>
      <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div id="two">
      <h2>LOREM IPSUM</h2>
      <br>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer auctor arcu ut tellus laoreet tristique. Aliquam erat volutpat. Ut sed lectus at lectus ultricies volutpat. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere
        ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. Duis posuere ex aliquet, auctor ante ullamcorper, volutpat lorem. volutpat lo..</p>
      <br>
      <p>
        <p>
          https://google.com/
        </p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you @Dogukan Cavus! This resolves the vertical alignment, however, the margins for #one still don't match up with #two?